# error in using class objects?

Tags: c++, class, constructor

i just made a person class and defined 2 overloaded constructors as u see
then made an array of 2 objects but some error pops up !

why i get these 2 errors guys please ??
and what's the [-fpermissive] error ??

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class person
{
    int x;

public:
    person() {
        x=0;
    }
    person(int y){   //error
        x=y;
    }
};


int main()
{
    int n;

    cin>>n;

    person* Arr= new person[2];

    Arr[0]=new person(n);  //error
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't post the errors, but I assume they were,

```
: In function ‘int main()’:
:25:24: error: invalid conversion from ‘person*’ to ‘int’ [-fpermissive]
:11:5: error:   initializing argument 1 of ‘person::person(int)’ [-fpermissive]
```

You have two options. One, make an array of person pointers that point to person objects you create with the "new" keyword and that reside on the heap.

```
person* Arr[2];
Arr[0]=new person(n);
```

You could also make an array of persons and then set them equal to another person, which doesn't require the new keyword. These would reside on the stack.

```
person Arr[2];
Arr[0]= person(n);
```

Comment: There are more than two options.  In fact, the first option is categorically bad.  If a dynamic array is desired, then the correct solution is `std::vector`.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Unless you only need sequential access, then `std::list` would be better.

Comment: @Code-Guru: Even with that confusion out of the way [deleted], I would disagree that "needing only sequential access" is a sufficient enough reason to choose list over vector.  You need a really special reason to choose list, some advantage that vector does not offer (I can choose to access a vector only sequentially), and you need to make sure that advantage isn't offset by vector's own advantages.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Certainly. I guess I need to be more clear when I make such brash comments. This was my round-about way of pointing out that such considerations need to be made when picking *a* correct solution (which still may not be the *only* correct solution).

Comment: @Code-Guru, Benjamin I think the only time you'd pick a `list` over a `vector` would be when you need to add/remove elements without invalidating iterators. As for "only sequential access" `vector` would surely be better there too because it would behave better with regards to caching.

Comment: @Code-Guru 'Unless you only need sequential access, then std::list would be better'-- Bjarne disagrees: "Vector is the default container
...prefer vector for storing elements unless there's a  good reason not to". He has the performance measurements to back that up (largely because of caching), but I can't find it at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

You allocated an array consisting of 2 `person`s, then tried to store a *pointer* to a newly allocated `person` into the first `person` in that array. Here's a minimal change to your code, using an array of pointers to `person`. (I'm not addressing whether this is good design.)

```
int main()
{
    int n;

    cin>>n;

    person** Arr= new person*[2];

    Arr[0]=new person(n);
    return 0;
}
```